# Evaluating infinte sum of gamma distributions

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a function which consists of an infinite series of a gamma distribution:

$f(z) = (\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Gamma(k/2)(\sqrt{2}z)^k/k!)$

Using the definition of the gamma distribution I have rewritten it to:

$f(z) = (\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k/2)!(\sqrt{2}z)^k/k!)$

However I cannot find an immediate way to reduce it to a computational expression. I have considered the solutions [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384355/method-to-evaluate-an-infinite-sum-of-ratio-of-gamma-functions-how-does-mathema) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419869/sum-of-infinite-series-with-the-gamma-function). But I am unable to solve it still.

I am not used to working with infinite series, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct identity is $\Gamma(k+1)= k! = k\Gamma(k)$, so $$f(z)=\frac 1 2 \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac k 2\right)}{\Gamma(k+1)} 2^{\frac k 2}z^k\tag{1}$$
$$\begin{split}
f^\prime(z) &= \frac 1 2 \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{k\Gamma\left(\frac k 2\right)}{\Gamma(k+1)} 2^{\frac k 2}z^{k-1}\\
&= \frac 1 2 \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac k 2\right)}{\Gamma(k)} 2^{\frac k 2}z^{k-1}\\
&= \frac 1 2 \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac 1 2\right)}{\Gamma(1)}\sqrt{2} + \frac 1 2\sum_{p\geq 1} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac {p+1} 2\right)}{\Gamma(p+1)} 2^{\frac {p+1} 2}z^{p}\\
f^{\prime\prime}(z) &= \frac 1 2\sum_{p\geq 1} \frac{p\Gamma\left(\frac {p+1} 2\right)}{\Gamma(p+1)} 2^{\frac {p+1} 2}z^{p-1}\\
&= \frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(2)}+\frac 1 2\sum_{p\geq 2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac {p+1} 2\right)}{\Gamma(p)} 2^{\frac {p+1} 2}z^{p-1}\\
&= 1+\frac 1 2\sum_{q\geq 1} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac {q} 2+1\right)}{\Gamma(q+1)} 2^{\frac {q} 2+1}z^{q}\\
&= 1+\frac 1 2\sum_{q\geq 1} \frac{\frac q 2\Gamma\left(\frac {q} 2\right)}{q\Gamma(q)} 2^{\frac {q} 2+1}z^{q}\\
&= 1 + \frac 1 2f(z)
\end{split}$$
Solving this O.D.E. yields:
$$f(z) = \alpha e^{\frac x{\sqrt{2}}} + \beta e^{-\frac x{\sqrt{2}}}-2$$
The initial conditions are $f(0) = 0$ and $f^\prime(0)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac 1 2\right)}{\Gamma(2)}\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2\pi}$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you your answer. As stated in my question, I am not familiar with working with infiinte series. From the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723062/calculate-sum-of-infinite-series-by-solving-a-differential-equation, it is a general method find the value of an infinite sum through an ODE. Can I ask you to elaborate on the intuition behind doing so?

Comment: Yes, finding an ODE is a classic way to solve this type of problem. This is particularly useful when it's not obvious how to relate the series to a known series. BTW, I don't guarantee that my calculations are correct, I tend to make mistakes  :)

Comment: That is alright, you got me further than I would have  on my own, so thank you.

Comment: Then I'm happy!